# Starting a new line after the first bracket doesn't automatically tab the new line

Tags: c++, visual-studio, format

when i go from a first bracket to another line like this,

```
int please()
{ 
<-- my cursor starts here,
}
int help)
{
    <-- I want it to start from here.
}
```

I'm using visual studio and c++

Comment: Did this not work? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-c-cpp-formatting?view=vs-2019

Comment: May be you just started editing a new file but didn't save it yet? Once you save it with a .cpp extension (or something similar), I bet the syntax highlighting and the auto-indentation work as expected.

Comment: It could be related to syntax problem. Could make two sections: the first with the initial state of the code and position of the cursor, the second with the position of the cursor after you have hit enter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you could try to check the `Automatically format braces when they are automatically completed`. Click **Tools -> Options ->Text Editor -> c/c++ ->Formatting ->General.**

[image]